# How to send parameter from JSP to servlet using Ajax call?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I need to send a parameter to a servlet through an ajax call i am trying with this code but it is not working.I am posting my code and the way i catch it to the Servlet...

```
 function loadJson() {
   $.ajax({
     url: "JsonServlet",
     type: "post",
     dataType: "json",
     data: {
       "value": "2"
     },
     error: function () {
       alert("error occured!!!");
     },
     success: function (data) {
       alert(data.value);
     }
   });
 }
```

and here is  where i am calling the function

```
<form enctype="application/json" method="post">
  <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="loadJson()" />
</form>
```

and in servlet i am using String `value=request.getParameter("value");`

i am using   `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>` jQuery file somebody please help

Comment: Are you getting to your servlet? What exactly is the problem? Is it on the browser, or the server. Do you have logs or errors? Have you looked with a debugger on the server (or the browser)?

Comment: Please don't forget to add a '?' to questions!  Some people do a search in the page for '?' and if none exists in the 'question' go directly to the next (actual) question in line.  Also note that 'jsp page' expands to 'java server page page' i.e. it is redundant to add 'page'.

Comment: Is it the same behavior without the `enctype` attribute? You'd also need to stop the submit button's default processing.

Comment: @DaveNewton yes its same

Comment: What's being sent on the wire?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch not i am not getting value to the Servlet but cn you tell me what is the error.  when i click on submit i get error occured message

Comment: @DaveNewton i did not get that what did you say

Comment: @DaveNewton and I both want to know what you're actually sending on the button press. Which browser are you using and do you have the dev tools? If not, and you're on Windows you could grab [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/)... but you could just use the browser dev tools.

Comment: i want to send value :2 in the servlet and i am using google chrome and i dont hav dev tools

Comment: is  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script> not supporting??

Comment: i still dont have the answer plese help

Comment: If you have Chrome then you have the dev tools. Check your JS console and network tabs.

Comment: can anyone test this small code and help me i am not able to do that

Answer (score 0):

Remove quotes in the data given. Are you getting any exceptions/error. use chrome developer tools, you can evaluate your code in that. It will give all details.

You can use JSON.stringify while giving data if you are expecting json object.

Comment: i have removed the quotes but still have the problem

Comment: Try to set contentType: "application/json;", hope you are using correct charset.

Comment: $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "any URL",
 data: JSON.stringify({ }),
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 dataType: "json",.....

Comment: where is the value here that i want to send?

Comment: you can place it in data, JSON.stringify. It is used to convert JavaScript data structures into JSON text

Comment: means i will place   data: JSON.stringify({}),